# How do I open specific ports on Linux (an AWS instance of RHEL v. 7)?

Tags: linux, security, firewall, tcp, port-scanning

I'm using RedHat version 7.  My AWS instances are in a security group with ample permissions for inbound connectivity.  I can do Yum updates.  The servers can ping each other.  I can transfer files from my workstation to the servers.  I even temporarily allowed all traffic from any IP address.  This didn't seem to help me.

I understand that RedHat v7 doesn't use IP tables by default.  RedHat v.7 uses firewalld or something similar.  I tried shutting off the firewall.

I used this command to configure the firewall: system-config-firewall-tui
I unchecked the "Enabled" option for the firewall and saved changes.

I ran these commands:
  systemctl stop iptables
  systemctl stop firewalld
  systemctl disable firewalld

I have root permissions.  The nmap utility indicates that almost every port is blocked.  I tried the nmap utility against specific ports and multiple ports from one Linux server to itself and a second Linux server on the network to the original Linux server.  I would get something like this:

Host is up (0.00042s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE VERSION
6379/tcp closed unknown

I double checked the nmap results with a bash script with these lines:

exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/6379 || echo "Not listening on port 6379"
exec 6>&- # close output connection
exec 6<&- # close input connection

The above bash script indicated that the port was closed.
(The script was from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609130/quick-way-to-find-if-a-port-is-open-on-linux)

I enabled the iptables just to see if a firewall needed to be running.  I ran this to try to open port 6379:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT

The above command has no response.  I just go to another prompt.

What can I do to open port 6379?  It seems like only port 22 is open.

Answer (score 0):

from 'outside' of AWS you may find that the majority of your ports are fire-walled off from any EC2 instances.

you need to go into your EC2 Security settings and enable access to those TCP ports ( from any IP addresses that you wish to have access to them.

Comment: Are you talking about Network & Security -> Security Groups?  When I log into the AWS Management Console (GUI), I go to Services -> All AWS Services -> EC2, I see Network & Security.  From there I go to Security Groups.

I have inbound rules allowing all traffic across all protocols throughout all ports for the IP address I use to connect to each of the two Linux servers I have.

I also have inbound rules allowing all traffic across all protocols throughout all ports for the IP address that I see when I type ifconfig on each of the two Linux servers I have.  What should I do now?

Comment: Have you assigned those security groups to your running instances?

Comment: Yes.  The Security Groups column in the "Instances" section shows they are using the security group wherein I edited a rule.  This rule allows all traffic across all ports among the AWS instances.